# How to use stack instead of list?

Tags: c#, xna

As part of my requirements, I need to use a stack instead of a list throughout my code. I've done quite a bit of research on using the stack class however I'm finding it difficult to find any examples in C# XNA.

After tweaking my code, I managed to make most of it compatible however I'm struggling to make the following code compatible with stack:

```
    private void UpdateCrystals(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gems.Count; ++i)
        {
            Crystal crystal = crystals[i];

            crystal.Update(gameTime);

            if (crystal.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle))
            {
                crystals.RemoveAt(i--);
                OnGemCollected(crystal, Player);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Doing it with a stack would be somewhat reverse, currently you're selecting the elements like 0, 1, 2, 3 ... With a stack it would be -> 3, 2, 1, 0 Last in first out

Comment: How would I go about implementing that? I'm assuming I'll have to copy the stack into an array and index it? So it would be something like:

Comment: how bout some up votes?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use .push() and .pop() for stacks
you can find more at msdn about stacks
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx

Comment: instead of removeat use a loop a temp stack to cycle through and pop the correct element and push them back on to the original stack

Answer (score 1):

Well it would be something like:

```
// note the i++ instead of ++i ...
for (int i = 0; i < gems.Count; i++)
{
   // gives you the element on top of the stack
   Crystal crystal = crystals.Peek();

   // do other stuff here

   if (crystal.BoundingCircle.Equals(Player.BoundingRectangle))
   {
       // removes the element on top of the stack (the last one entered)
       crystals.Pop();

       // do even more stuff here ...
   }
}
```

Here I'm assuming that `crystals` is `Stack<Crystal>`

Also as a side note: `crystals.Push(new Crystal());` would add an element on top of the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the example. My code seems to running without exception errors now however it's not running as it's suppose to. I'll have a look into it a bit more and see if I can work it out.

Comment: Yeah, just keep in mind that a stack is always top to bottom, also your for loop should be `i++` if you wanna go through all the items. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I think your code at [C# Stack not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621379/c-sharp-stack-not-updating/16621586#16621586). Could you go there and see what's answer for this case?

Comment: Thanks. I am new so I just want to contributing something for community. Cheers!