# C# Stack not updating

Tags: c#, list, xna, stack

For some reason the code that I modified doesn't seem to be functioning correctly. There were no exception error when debugging however it does not function the same as in the original code (list) - that is it doesn't seem to update. I've targeted it down to an area of code where I believe is causing the problem:

My original code (using List) that works:

```
    private List<Gem> gems = new List<Gem>();
    private List<Enemy> enemies = new List<Enemy>();

    private void UpdateGems(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gems.Count; ++i)
        {
            Gem gem = gems[i];

            gem.Update(gameTime);

            if (gem.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle))
            {
                gems.RemoveAt(i--);
                OnGemCollected(gem, Player);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my modified code replacing List to Stack which doesn't work correctly:

```
    private Stack<Gem> gems = new Stack<Gem>();
    private Stack<Enemy> enemies = new Stack<Enemy>();

    private void UpdateGems(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gems.Count; ++i)
        {
            Gem gem = gems.Peek();


            gem.Update(gameTime);


            if (gem.BoundingCircle.Equals(Player.BoundingRectangle))
            {
                gems.Pop();

                OnGemCollected(gem, Player);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work correctly"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that it doesn't seem to update.

Comment: #1 has gem.BoundingCircle.Intersects and #2 has gem.BoundingCircle.Equals Other than that you should get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you need, but the *loop looks a little strange*: if you don't `pop()` anything from the stack at the first turn, `peek()` will return  the same element always.
**Stack data structure is not indexed**, it allow just to pop/peek the **last pushed element**. The code with the list behave of course different since you are actually checking all the elements in the list.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose my problem is how I can index the stack data structure.

Comment: @Katie by the data structure definition, you can't index a stack.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, when you pop something off a stack you remove the last item added. Because of this you have reversed the order in which you are checking and removing `Gem` objects from the collection - when you do the `Peek` and `Pop` and `BoundingCircle.Equals()` check in the `Stack<Gem>` version you are not checking the first item in the collection like you are in the `List<Gem>` version.

A List can be iterated in either direction, just adjust your indexer in the appropriate way. A [Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) is LIFO (Last In, First Out), so you can only access the last item added.

Comment: Can you provide an example on how I could check it in the Stack<Gem> version?

Comment: @Katie to get the checking in the same order you would need to reverse the iteration count on the list: `int i = gems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--`. You can't reverse a stack - it's LIFO (Last In, First Out). Maybe a stack is not suitable for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I think when called to peak method, it maybe keep a references to that item on the top of stack collection. So when you called to pop method. It gonna working not correctly.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I have copy your example and put to a console application as below

```
class Program
    {
        private static Stack<Gem> gems = new Stack<Gem>();
        private Stack<Enemy> enemies = new Stack<Enemy>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            gems.Push(new Gem
                {
                   BoundingCircle = new BoundingCircle
                       {
                           Name = "abc"
                       }
                });

            gems.Push(new Gem
            {
                BoundingCircle = new BoundingCircle
                {
                    Name = "def"
                }
            });

            UpdateGems(new GameTime());
        }

        private static void UpdateGems(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < gems.Count; ++i)
            {
                Gem gem = gems.Peek();


                gem.Update(gameTime);


                if (gem.BoundingCircle.Equals(Player.BoundingRectangle))
                {
                    gems.Pop();

                    OnGemCollected(gem, null);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void OnGemCollected(Gem gem, Player player)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Gem
    {
        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

        }

        public BoundingCircle BoundingCircle { get; set; }
    }

    public class Enemy
    {

    }

    public class GameTime
    {

    }

    public class BoundingCircle : Bounding
    {
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var temp = (Bounding) obj;
            return Name.Equals(temp.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }

    public class Player
    {
        static Player()
        {
            BoundingRectangle = new BoundingRectangle
                {
                    Name = "def"
                };
        }

        public static BoundingRectangle BoundingRectangle { get; set; }
    }

    public class BoundingRectangle : Bounding
    {

    }

    public abstract class Bounding
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

It worked fine. Please notice that your Equals function have to be overridden by the BoundingCircle class.